# React + Django send raw password in HTTP request, security discussion

Tags: reactjs, django, passwords, restful-authentication

I am new to Django and I am working on the user authentication part. I used the Django provided User model, and use auth() and login() method when the user login.

I have a question about the password security and hope have some discussion here.

When the auth() function hashed the raw password and then compares the username and the hashed password. That means the front end needs to send the password in raw data. (Otherwise, it will be hashed twice).

Is it not safe to send the password in raw data? If I want to hash the password in the frontend then send the request to Django, what can I do in this case?

Comment: It should be fine if you are using a post request and sending the password in the body

Comment: thanks, i did some research and I think it should be fine if we do it in HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

It's OK if you pass password in `post` request

But for more security, you can encrypt data ...

Comment: In React? I was considering about that but auth() method will encrypt the password again before compare to the database